# How did スマート (from 'smart' in English) shift to mean 'slim, trim' and 'stylish'?

Tags: etymology, loanwords

I first learned of this loanword on [/r/FalseFriends](https://redd.it/3bu20c). [Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)

> #### Etymology
>
> From [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language) *[smart](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smart#English)*.
>
> #### Adjectival noun
>
> **スマート** (*-na inflection*, *rōmaji* **[sumāto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sum%C4%81to#Japanese)**)
>
> 1. [slim](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slim), [trim](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trim),
>    [slender](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slender)
> 2. [stylish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stylish)

1. What type of [semantic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Typology_by_Blank_(1999)) is this?
2. Please see the titled question.

Comment: Well, 'smart' in English can mean 'well-dressed'. Maybe it's more common here in England though.

Comment: I don't think it's that regional. Normal to hear "you're looking smart" or something to that effect.

Comment: In the 70s-90s, most electrical appliances got smaller and smarter every time new model's released. I guess their advertisement tells something like `よりスマートに` to tell that it has a powerful processor or something like that but people misunderstand as `slim`,`trim` because most of the time, they get smaller too.

Comment: I'm not sure what shift you are referring to. "smart" has had such a meaning in English for a long time. Someone who is *smartly* dressed, for example. Just expressed strictly as a loanword.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a semantic shift nor are they false friends. In English, *smart* has several distinct meanings. It has been used for to look stylish for a long time. It is *still used* for this meaning, albeit less commonly and mainly in British English varieties. Using it for intelligence is more colloquial and has developed more recently (and is more common in American English varieties).

> **smart adjective** (STYLISH) mainly UK
>
> having a clean, tidy, and stylish appearance.
>
> **smart adjective** (INTELLIGENT) mainly US
>
> intelligent, or able to think quickly or intelligently in difficult situations.
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smart)
>
> [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smart)

The Japanese スマート has been derived from the *original* meaning. Of course, the Japanese language is changing as well, it is now also used for smartphones, just as it is in English.